# Flutter inputformatter for date

Tags: flutter

I am looking for an example of an inputformatter for text field that will be a date mm/dd/yyyy, what I am trying to do as the user types update the format.  For instance user starts to type mm and the / is put in, then when the dd is typed in the / is put in.

Anyone done this or have an example?  I have done it in other languages but could not find a similar way to do in flutter/dart.

This is what I have tried so far, but can not get the logic correct.  Any ideas?

```
    class _DateFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue,
      TextEditingValue newValue
      ) {
    final int newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
    int usedSubstringIndex = 0;
    final StringBuffer newText = new StringBuffer();
    if (newTextLength == 2) {
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(0, 2) + '/ ');
      if (newValue.selection.end == 3)
        selectionIndex+=3;
    }
    if (newTextLength == 5) {
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(0, 5) + '/ ');
      if (newValue.selection.end == 6)
        selectionIndex += 6;
    }
    // Dump the rest.
    if (newTextLength >= usedSubstringIndex)
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex));
    return new TextEditingValue(
      text: newText.toString(),
      selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a datepicker instead of let the user types?

Comment: @JorgeVieira, my users specifically tell me they want to type and do not want to have to click. Granted, we are using Flutter Web, so it's a different context than the typical Flutter app.

Answer (score 12):

I was struggling with this too. I ended up with the following not so elegant solution:

```
class DateInputTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _DateInputTextFieldState();
  }
}

class _DateInputTextFieldState extends State<DateInputTextField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      inputFormatters: [DateTextFormatter()],
      onChanged: (String value) {},
    );
  }
}

class DateTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {

    //this fixes backspace bug
    if (oldValue.text.length >= newValue.text.length) {
      return newValue;
    }

    var dateText = _addSeperators(newValue.text, '/');
    return newValue.copyWith(text: dateText, selection: updateCursorPosition(dateText));
  }

  String _addSeperators(String value, String seperator) {
    value = value.replaceAll('/', '');
    var newString = '';
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      newString += value[i];
      if (i == 1) {
        newString += seperator;
      }
      if (i == 3) {
        newString += seperator;
      }
    }
    return newString;
  }

  TextSelection updateCursorPosition(String text) {
    return TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: text.length));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is an improved version based on Jochem Toolenaar answer. This version will automatically remove the forward slashes for you and limit the user to 8 digits.

```
class DateTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  static const _maxChars = 8;

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    var text = _format(newValue.text, '/');
    return newValue.copyWith(text: text, selection: updateCursorPosition(text));
  }

  String _format(String value, String seperator) {
    value = value.replaceAll(seperator, '');
    var newString = '';

    for (int i = 0; i < min(value.length, _maxChars); i++) {
      newString += value[i];
      if ((i == 1 || i == 3) && i != value.length - 1) {
        newString += seperator;
      }
    }

    return newString;
  }

  TextSelection updateCursorPosition(String text) {
    return TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: text.length));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding an updated version based on Arizona1911 and Jochem Toolenaar versions.

This one prevents the caret from jumping when modifying some of the text that was already typed.

[image]

```
class DateTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  static const _maxChars = 8;

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue,
    TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {
    String separator = '/';
    var text = _format(
      newValue.text,
      oldValue.text,
      separator,
    );

    return newValue.copyWith(
      text: text,
      selection: updateCursorPosition(
        oldValue,
        text,
      ),
    );
  }

  String _format(
    String value,
    String oldValue,
    String separator,
  ) {
    var isErasing = value.length < oldValue.length;
    var isComplete = value.length > _maxChars + 2;

    if (!isErasing && isComplete) {
      return oldValue;
    }

    value = value.replaceAll(separator, '');
    final result = <String>[];

    for (int i = 0; i < min(value.length, _maxChars); i++) {
      result.add(value[i]);
      if ((i == 1 || i == 3) && i != value.length - 1) {
        result.add(separator);
      }
    }

    return result.join();
  }

  TextSelection updateCursorPosition(
    TextEditingValue oldValue,
    String text,
  ) {
    var endOffset = max(
      oldValue.text.length - oldValue.selection.end,
      0,
    );

    var selectionEnd = text.length - endOffset;

    return TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: selectionEnd));
  }
}
```

Thanks to [caseyryan/flutter_multi_formatter](https://github.com/caseyryan/flutter_multi_formatter)

Answer (score 1):

In the above solution, I found one overlapping problem with editing in between dates ( if try to edit the month field, the year values get overlapping)

### So, I found one solution for this, But not an optimized solution, but it is covering almost all the scenarios,

```
     1. forward slash during adding fields
     2. remove the forward slash on on clearing fields
     3. between editing handling
      ...etc
    

class CustomDateTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    var text = _format(newValue.text, '/', oldValue);
    return newValue.copyWith(
        text: text, selection: _updateCursorPosition(text, oldValue));
  }
}

String _format(String value, String seperator, TextEditingValue old) {
  var finalString = '';
  var dd = '';
  var mm = '';
  var yyy = '';
  var oldVal = old.text;
  print('<------------------------- start---------------------------->');
  print('oldVal -> $oldVal');
  print('value -> $value');
  var temp_oldVal = oldVal;
  var temp_value = value;
  if (!oldVal.contains(seperator) ||
      oldVal.isEmpty ||
      seperator.allMatches(oldVal).length < 2) {
    oldVal += '///';
  }
  if (!value.contains(seperator) || _backSlashCount(value) < 2) {
    value += '///';
  }
  var splitArrOLD = oldVal.split(seperator);
  var splitArrNEW = value.split(seperator);
  print('----> splitArrOLD: $splitArrOLD');
  print('----> splitArrNEW: $splitArrNEW');
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    splitArrOLD[i] = splitArrOLD[i].toString().trim();
    splitArrNEW[i] = splitArrNEW[i].toString().trim();
  }
  // block erasing
  if ((splitArrOLD[0].isNotEmpty &&
      splitArrOLD[2].isNotEmpty &&
      splitArrOLD[1].isEmpty &&
      temp_value.length < temp_oldVal.length &&
      splitArrOLD[0] == splitArrNEW[0] &&
      splitArrOLD[2].toString().trim() ==
          splitArrNEW[1].toString().trim()) ||
      (_backSlashCount(temp_oldVal) > _backSlashCount(temp_value) &&
          splitArrNEW[1].length > 2) ||
      (splitArrNEW[0].length > 2 && _backSlashCount(temp_oldVal) == 1) ||
      (_backSlashCount(temp_oldVal) == 2 &&
          _backSlashCount(temp_value) == 1 &&
          splitArrNEW[0].length > splitArrOLD[0].length)) {
    finalString = temp_oldVal; // making the old date as it is
    print('blocked finalString : $finalString ');
  } else {
    if (splitArrNEW[0].length > splitArrOLD[0].length) {
      if (splitArrNEW[0].length < 3) {
        dd = splitArrNEW[0];
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          dd += splitArrNEW[0][i];
        }
      }
      if (dd.length == 2 && !dd.contains(seperator)) {
        dd += seperator;
      }
    } else if (splitArrNEW[0].length == splitArrOLD[0].length) {
      print('splitArrNEW[0].length == 2');
      if (oldVal.length > value.length && splitArrNEW[1].isEmpty) {
        dd = splitArrNEW[0];
      } else {
        dd = splitArrNEW[0] + seperator;
      }
    } else if (splitArrNEW[0].length < splitArrOLD[0].length) {
      print('splitArrNEW[0].length < splitArrOLD[0].length');
      if (oldVal.length > value.length &&
          splitArrNEW[1].isEmpty &&
          splitArrNEW[0].isNotEmpty) {
        dd = splitArrNEW[0];
      } else if (temp_oldVal.length > temp_value.length &&
          splitArrNEW[0].isEmpty &&
          _backSlashCount(temp_value) == 2) {
        dd += seperator;
      } else {
        if (splitArrNEW[0].isNotEmpty) {
          dd = splitArrNEW[0] + seperator;
        }
      }
    }
    print('dd value --> $dd');

    if (dd.isNotEmpty) {
      finalString = dd;
      if (dd.length == 2 &&
          !dd.contains(seperator) &&
          oldVal.length < value.length &&
          splitArrNEW[1].isNotEmpty) {
        if (seperator.allMatches(dd).isEmpty) {
          finalString += seperator;
        }
      } else if (splitArrNEW[2].isNotEmpty &&
          splitArrNEW[1].isEmpty &&
          temp_oldVal.length > temp_value.length) {
        if (seperator.allMatches(dd).isEmpty) {
          finalString += seperator;
        }
      } else if (oldVal.length < value.length &&
          (splitArrNEW[1].isNotEmpty || splitArrNEW[2].isNotEmpty)) {
        if (seperator.allMatches(dd).isEmpty) {
          finalString += seperator;
        }
      }
    } else if (_backSlashCount(temp_oldVal) == 2 && splitArrNEW[1].isNotEmpty) {
      dd += seperator;
    }
    print('finalString after dd=> $finalString');
    if (splitArrNEW[0].length == 3 && splitArrOLD[1].isEmpty) {
      mm = splitArrNEW[0][2];
    }

    if (splitArrNEW[1].length > splitArrOLD[1].length) {
      print('splitArrNEW[1].length > splitArrOLD[1].length');
      if (splitArrNEW[1].length < 3) {
        mm = splitArrNEW[1];
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          mm += splitArrNEW[1][i];
        }
      }
      if (mm.length == 2 && !mm.contains(seperator)) {
        mm += seperator;
      }
    } else if (splitArrNEW[1].length == splitArrOLD[1].length) {
      print('splitArrNEW[1].length = splitArrOLD[1].length');
      if (splitArrNEW[1].isNotEmpty) {
        mm = splitArrNEW[1];
      }
    } else if (splitArrNEW[1].length < splitArrOLD[1].length) {
      print('splitArrNEW[1].length < splitArrOLD[1].length');
      if (splitArrNEW[1].isNotEmpty) {
        mm = splitArrNEW[1] + seperator;
      }
    }
    print('mm value --> $mm');

    if (mm.isNotEmpty) {
      finalString += mm;
      if (mm.length == 2 && !mm.contains(seperator)) {
        if (temp_oldVal.length < temp_value.length) {
          finalString += seperator;
        }
      }
    }
    print('finalString after mm=> $finalString');
    if (splitArrNEW[1].length == 3 && splitArrOLD[2].isEmpty) {
      yyy = splitArrNEW[1][2];
    }

    if (splitArrNEW[2].length > splitArrOLD[2].length) {
      print('splitArrNEW[2].length > splitArrOLD[2].length');
      if (splitArrNEW[2].length < 5) {
        yyy = splitArrNEW[2];
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          yyy += splitArrNEW[2][i];
        }
      }
    } else if (splitArrNEW[2].length == splitArrOLD[2].length) {
      print('splitArrNEW[2].length == splitArrOLD[2].length');
      if (splitArrNEW[2].isNotEmpty) {
        yyy = splitArrNEW[2];
      }
    } else if (splitArrNEW[2].length < splitArrOLD[2].length) {
      print('splitArrNEW[2].length < splitArrOLD[2].length');
      yyy = splitArrNEW[2];
    }
    print('yyy value --> $yyy');

    if (yyy.isNotEmpty) {
      if (_backSlashCount(finalString) < 2) {
        if (splitArrNEW[0].isEmpty && splitArrNEW[1].isEmpty) {
          finalString = seperator + seperator + yyy;
        } else {
          finalString = finalString + seperator + yyy;
        }
      } else {
        finalString += yyy;
      }
    } else {
      if (_backSlashCount(finalString) > 1 && oldVal.length > value.length) {
        var valueUpdate = finalString.split(seperator);
        finalString = valueUpdate[0] + seperator + valueUpdate[1];
      }
    }

    print('finalString after yyyy=> $finalString');
  }

  print('<------------------------- finish---------------------------->');

  return finalString;
}

TextSelection _updateCursorPosition(String text, TextEditingValue oldValue) {
  var endOffset = max(
    oldValue.text.length - oldValue.selection.end,
    0,
  );
  var selectionEnd = text.length - endOffset;
  print('My log ---> $selectionEnd');
  return TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: selectionEnd));
}

int _backSlashCount(String value) {
  return '/'.allMatches(value).length;
}
```

### We can Use our custom formator as in inputFormatters like below

```
TextField(
  // maxLength: 10,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
  controller: _controllerDOB,
  focusNode: _focusNodeDOB,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    counterText: '',
  ),
  inputFormatters: [
    WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[0-9/]")),
    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
    CustomDateTextFormatter(),
  ],
),
```

Try out this, thank you. !

Answer (score 0):

I found this as a simple solution

```
inputFormatters: [
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^[0-9\/]*$')),
                  TextInputFormatter.withFunction((oldValue, newValue) {
                    String text = newValue.text;
                    if (newValue.text.length == 2 &&
                        oldValue.text.length !=3) {
                      text += '/';
                    }
                    if (newValue.text.length == 5 && oldValue.text.length !=6) {
                      text += '/';
                    }
                    return TextEditingValue(text: text);
                  })
                ],
```

Comment: You didn't understand it. From my side it's working absolutely fine. I have posted because someone is facing the same issue & I got solution while solving that. You are not a celebrity to come and comment on your post.  Here is my working code. If you can't test don't simply say it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

**An improvement of the original answer (Jochem Toolenaar and Alberto)**

This would also validate the month in mm/yy format. That is months such as 90, won't be valid.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

/// Date formatter that will automatically remove the forward slashes for you and limit the user to 8 digits. Also validates the month
class DateTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  static const _maxChars = 5;

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (!isValidDate(newValue.text)) {
      return oldValue;
    }
    var text = _format(newValue.text, '/');
    return newValue.copyWith(text: text, selection: updateCursorPosition(text));
  }

  String _format(String value, String separator) {
    value = value.replaceAll(separator, '');
    var newString = '';

    for (int i = 0; i < math.min(value.length, _maxChars); i++) {
      newString += value[i];
      if ((i == 1 || i == 3) && i != value.length - 1) {
        newString += separator;
      }
    }

    return newString;
  }

  TextSelection updateCursorPosition(String text) {
    return TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: text.length));
  }

  bool isValidDate(String value) {
    if (value.length == 1) {
      return ['0', '1'].contains(value);
    } else if (value.length == 2) {
      var number = int.parse(value);
      return number >= 1 && number <= 12;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that you have to include this line:

```dart
inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly, DateTextFormatter()]
```

To enable the input filter character that are not numbers

Answer (score -1):

I used Robert TextInputFormatter as follows

```
class DATETextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
@override
TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
  TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
int newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
int usedSubstringIndex = 0;
StringBuffer newText = new StringBuffer();
if (newTextLength == 3) {
  if (!newValue.text.contains('/')) {
    if (newValue.text[2] != '/') {
      newText
          .write(newValue.text.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 2) + '/');
    }
    if (newValue.selection.end >= 2) selectionIndex++;
  }
}
if (newTextLength == 6) {
  if (newValue.text[5] != '/') {
    newText.write(newValue.text.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 5) + 
'/');
  }
  if (newValue.selection.end >= 5) selectionIndex++;
}
// Dump the rest.
if (newTextLength >= usedSubstringIndex)
  newText.write(newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex));
return new TextEditingValue(
  text: newText.toString(),
  selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
);
} 
}
```

I call the class in a list of TextInputFormatter

```
List<TextInputFormatter> getTextInputFormatter(int idInputFormatter) {
...
return list = [
    **DATETextInputFormatter()**,
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9/]')),
    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)]
```

Finally in the TextFormField(

```
TextFormField(
...
autovalidateMode:AutovalidateMode.always,
inputFormatters:getTextInputFormatter(idInputFormatter),
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
validator: (value) {if (value == null ||                                              
value.isEmpty) { return 'need to inform date';}
if (value.length >= 10) {try {if (int.parse(value.substring(0, 
2))>12) {return 'invalid date';}if (int.parse(value.substring(3, 
5)) >31) {return 'invalid date';}var data =                                                  
DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy').parse(value);                                                  
//test date is between 100 old or 100 years ahead
return ((data.isAfter(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days:36500)))) ||                                                          
(data.isBefore(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days:36500)))))
? 'invalid date': null;} catch (e) {return 'invalid date';                                                
}
}
}
return null;
},
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly and provide more details on what you did. If you did exactly what someone originally answered, then you should have just commented on that answer instead

Answer (score -2):

```
class DateFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
    @override
    TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
        TextEditingValue oldValue,
        TextEditingValue newValue
        ) {
      final int newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
      int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
      int usedSubstringIndex = 0;
      final StringBuffer newText = StringBuffer();
      if (newTextLength >= 3) {
        newText.write(newValue.text.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 2) + '/');
        if (newValue.selection.end >= 2)
          selectionIndex++;
      }
      if (newTextLength >= 5) {
        newText.write(newValue.text.substring(2, usedSubstringIndex = 4) + '/');
        if (newValue.selection.end >= 4)
          selectionIndex++;
      }

      // Dump the rest.
      if (newTextLength >= usedSubstringIndex)
        newText.write(newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex));
      return TextEditingValue(`enter code here`
        text: newText.toString(),
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Hi @AkashDadnwate, welcome to Stack Overflow! As you're new here, I strongly recommend that you take a look at the guide [how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It'd be much better if you explain the code and clearly show how it solves the problem.

Comment: Please provide more details as to how your code fixes the OPs issue